# How can JavaScript detect that a CSS transition is undoing itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, transition

I have a fixed  bar in HTML which uses a transition to increase its height upon the mouse hovering over it, and scroll back up when it moves off. When the transition ends (i.e., the nav transitions to a larger height),  elements are created inside it. The thing is, I need the divs to disappear as soon as the nav scrolls back up. 
I know there is the transitionend event, which is what I used to signal to create the divs in the first place, but is there a JavaScript event for when the transition starts to recoil (not for when it completely ends, but when it starts to slide back up when the cursor is taken off)?

Comment: Since the transition recoils when the mouse leaves the area, you can use the mouseleave event.

Comment: If your question is: *"Is there a native event triggered by changes to a particular style property of a DOM element?"* Nope, there isn't. You have to write a listener for it yourself or rely on an event happening at the same time.

Comment: There is a `transitionstart` event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionstart), but it doesn't look very well-supported, plus it would probably get tricky to use (for example, if the "open" transition hadn't actually ended yet, would the reverse of that transition fire a separate start event?).  I think Ori's suggestion of just using the `mouseleave` event is going to be your best bet.